# unordered_map elements disappeared after [] operation in c++

Tags: c++

The behavior that unodered_map elements disappeared unexpectedly in the following C++ code confused me a whole lot.  In the first `for` loop I stored the remainder of each element in `time` moduled by 60 and its count in `unordered_map<int, int> m`, in the second  `for` loop, I printed the content in `m`, so far everything seems working right.
`cout` as following

```
0:1
39:1
23:1
18:1
44:1
59:1
12:1
38:1
56:2
17:1
37:1
24:1
58:1
```

However in the third `for` loop, it only printed part of elements in `m`,

```
0:1
39:1
58:1
0:1
```

it seems many elements in `m` were erased by `n += m[remainder]*m[60-remainder];` operation. I was so confused by this behavior, could you please understand what is going here? Really so confused.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<int> time ({418,204,77,278,239,457,284,263,372,279,476,416,360,18});
    int n =0;
    unordered_map<int,int> m; // <remiander,cnt>
    for (auto t:time)
        m[t%60]++;
    for (auto [remainder,cnt]:m)
         cout<<remainder<<":"<<cnt<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    for (auto [remainder,cnt]:m){
        cout<<remainder<<":"<<cnt<<endl;

        if (remainder==0 || remainder==30)
            n += cnt*(cnt-1)/2;
        else
            n += m[remainder]*m[60-remainder];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third loop uses the `[]` operator inside the loop.

```
for (auto [remainder,cnt]:m){

   // ...

   n += m[remainder]*m[60-remainder];
```

`unordered_map`'s `[]` invalidates all existing iterators if it results in a rehash. This includes the implicit iterators employed during range iteration.

As shown, `m[remainder]` cannot cause a rehash because it can only access an existing value in the unordered map, but this is not true for `m[60-remainder]`, resulting in undefined behavior.

You just need to remove this usage of the `[]` operator and replace it with the equivalent `find()` (and, of course, correctly handling the `end()` value if it gets returned).

Comment: Or alternatively use a vector instead of unordered_map, since the "remainder" range is always [0,60) due to the t%60.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Thank you very much for your quick help. But m[60-remainder] shall not cause undefined behavior according to https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/ if the key does not exist, it will implement insertion.

Comment: And [insertion can cause a rehash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at): "If an insertion occurs and results in a rehashing of the container, all iterators are invalidated".

Comment: thank you very much, Sam. Once again, I understand what it means that c++ prioritizes speed than safety. I primarily use Python, so I was super confused by some behavior in c++. But I learned new knowledge again. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlbertGLieu If you attempted the same in Python (insert into dict while iterating it), you could get an incomplete loop, or a runtime exception. Doing this is a bug in both languages, but it's true that undefined behaviour is less safe.

Comment: @eerorika In python, one generally can use ````for key in list(dict_)```` to avoid the rehash problem, thus there is no iterator invalidated issue.

Comment: @AlbertGLieu You can do a similar thing in C++, although not as elegantly.